# RethinkDB: how to do real upsert - insert new document on update fail?

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to insert new document on update fail - is there any way to do this? Now RethinkDB allows me only to update document on insert fail via {upsert: true} in insert command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a branch and an explicit merge.

`replace` is like `update`, except it completely replaces a document rather than merging with it.  The following are equivalent (in Ruby code):

```
table.get(id).update{|row| {a: row['a']+1}}
table.get(id).replace{|row| row.merge({a: row['a']+1})}
```

So if you want to do an "update", or else insert a row if there is no row, you could do this:

```
table.get(id).replace {|row|
  r.branch(
    row.eq(nil),
    INSERT_OBJECT,
    row.merge(UPDATE_OBJECT))
}
```

Comment: As I understand, table("smth") returns all entries from table - then you check if entry is null - how can it be null? If i'm trying to perform something after get request returned null, then Rethink throws error - that's the problem

Comment: are INSERT_OBJECT and UPDATE_OBJECT real things or just placeholders? :) do these actually need to be r.db("").table("").insert({}) and row.merge({field1: "", field2:"", field3: "", etc...}) ?

Comment: They're placeholders for objects.  So an example query would be

    r.table('test').get(0).replace {|row|
      r.branch(row.eq(nil), {id: 0, a: 0}, row.merge({a: 0}))
    }

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a clean way? I would like to do the same as a Redis http://redis.io/commands/zincrby where I want to increment a counter or add a document with a count of 1 in case it does not exist. Im not seeing from the example how this would work.